# How to handle UndeliverableException error thrown via blockingFirst() in Micronaut?

Tags: rx-java2, micronaut

Below is a snippet from my micronaut web service:

```
      try {
         val result = hClient.exchange(GET<String>("$readEndpoint/$token")).blockingFirst()
         logger.error("result")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error(e.message)
        }
```

`hClient` is a reactive http client injected as `@Inject val hClient: RxHttpClient`

> The endpoint is throwing "Connection reset by peer" exception.

**Issue I am facing**

Even though I have wrapped code in try and catch, An exception `io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException` is thrown and not caught.

I basically get two exceptions thrown, one is caught by catch block with message `Error occurred reading HTTP response: Connection reset by peer`, another one is flowing up to service with message `io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException`

**Reproducible via below code**

Keep timeout too less to receive a timeout error.

```
micronaut:   
    http:
        client:
            read-timeout: 1s
```

```
@Controller("/")
class TokenController(
    @Client("https://hello123456789.com/dummy") @Inject val hClient: RxHttpClient
) {

    @Get("/test")
    fun refresh(): String {

        try {
            val result = hClient.exchange(HttpRequest.GET<String>("/token/1234")).blockingFirst()
            println("result")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message)
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Googling told me that I need to add global onError to rxjava but couldn't find how to do that in Micronaut.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Even though I have wrapped code in try and catch, An exception io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException is thrown and not caught." That isn't possible

Comment: @JamesKleeh  I have updated snippet in question. It is reproducible with that.

Comment: Could you report an issue with steps to reproduce the exception. Thanks.